# Navigation property is not populated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm reproducing an issue with EF Core 7.0.8 in a C# console application and a simple model.

```cs
using ConsoleApp1;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using var db = new ProductContext();

Console.WriteLine("Get product df86dd7f-727d-462f-93e8-6a9caf577a42");
var query = db.Products
    .Include(_ => _.ProductModel)
    .Include(_ => _.SizeUnitMeasure)
    .Include(_ => _.WeightUnitMeasure)
    .Where(_ => _.ObjectId == Guid.Parse("df86dd7f-727d-462f-93e8-6a9caf577a42"));

var queryString = query.ToQueryString();
var product = query.First();

Console.WriteLine($"Product name: {product.Name}");
```

The ProductContext class:

```cs
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    override protected void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("myConnectionString");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .ToTable("Product")
            .HasKey(_ => _.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .Property(_ => _.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ProductId");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOne(_ => _.SizeUnitMeasure)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(_ => _.SizeUnitMeasureCode);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOne(_ => _.WeightUnitMeasure)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(_ => _.WeightUnitMeasureCode);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UnitMeasure>()
            .ToTable("UnitMeasure")
            .HasKey(_ => _.UnitMeasureCode);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductModel>()
            .ToTable("ProductModel")
            .HasKey(_ => _.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductModel>()
            .Property(_ => _.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ProductModelID");
    }
}
```

The entity classes:

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Guid ObjectId { get; private set; }
    public string? Name { get; private set; }
    public ProductModel? ProductModel { get; private set; }
    public string? SizeUnitMeasureCode { get; private set; }
    public UnitMeasure? SizeUnitMeasure { get; set; }
    public string? WeightUnitMeasureCode { get; private set; }
    public UnitMeasure? WeightUnitMeasure { get; set; }
}

public class ProductModel
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Guid ObjectId { get; private set; }
    public string? Name { get; private set; }
}

public class UnitMeasure
{
    public string? UnitMeasureCode { get; private set; }
    public Guid ObjectId { get; private set; }
    public string? Name { get; private set; }
}
```

The Product entity has navigation properties to the ProductModel and UnitMeasure entities.
The problem is that the SizeUnitMeasure and WeightUnitMeasure properties are not populated after the query has run whereas the ProductModel property is.
The query that EF produces seems correct. The joins to the ProductModel and UnitMeasure tables look ok and return the correct results:

```sql
SELECT [p].[ProductId], [p].[Name], [p].[ObjectId], [p].[ProductModelId], [p].[SizeUnitMeasureCode], [p].[WeightUnitMeasureCode], [p0].[ProductModelID], [p0].[Name], [p0].[ObjectId], [u].[UnitMeasureCode], [u].[Name], [u].[ObjectId], [u0].[UnitMeasureCode], [u0].[Name], [u0].[ObjectId]
FROM [Product] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [ProductModel] AS [p0] ON [p].[ProductModelId] = [p0].[ProductModelID]
LEFT JOIN [UnitMeasure] AS [u] ON [p].[SizeUnitMeasureCode] = [u].[UnitMeasureCode]
LEFT JOIN [UnitMeasure] AS [u0] ON [p].[WeightUnitMeasureCode] = [u0].[UnitMeasureCode]
WHERE [p].[ObjectId] = 'df86dd7f-727d-462f-93e8-6a9caf577a42'
```

What could be wrong here?
I've also tinkered with the property setters of the Product class. The UnitMeasure property setters are public now but it really doesn't make a difference; the setter of the ProductModel is still private and that one works fine.

I've also tried to rename the SizeUnitMeasureCode column to SizeUnitMeasureUnitMeasureCode to avoid the HasForeignKey configuration that's in the ProductContext class. But that also doesn't solve the issue; the SizeUnitMeasure property remains null.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't use `_` for lambda parameter names because `_` is the conventional name for discards.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on EFCore, but I'm pretty sure you need to add `DbSet<UnitMeasure>` and `DbSet<ProductModel>` properties to your `DbContext` in order to use loaded-related-entities - otherwise they're untracked... I think?

Comment: @Dai, you are wrong with that assumption. EFCore will happily track dependent entities without a corresponding DbSet in the context class.

Comment: Most probably you are initializing the reference navigation properties with `= new(...)`. You can find other posts here explaining why you shouldn't.

Comment: Nope, I'm not initializing the navigation properties. The entity classes are now included above. Even if I initialize the ProductModel property for example, it's still populated correctly. If I initialize the SizeUniteMeasure property, it's not overwritten by EF Core.